# My Android ADT Project Explorer Window Has Disappeared

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

[image][image]I have tried Window -> Show View -> Project Explorer but nothing happens. Any ideas ?

Comment: maybe you are looking for package explorer?

Comment: can't get it to show either ...

Comment: It does show for me when I try: Window -> Show View -> Project Explorer.  I am on the latest ADT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a solution, but alternatively you could try using `Package Explorer` view. It shows the same information than `Project Explorer`, but a little more organized imho.

**EDIT**

Buttons in the tab below could help.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

The problem was actually that the bottom Pane was maximized. Double-clicking one of its tabs solved the issue.

Comment: i'm afraid it has gone AWOL also

Comment: is there any way to reset the entire IDE config ?

Comment: Mmh weird, just in case... did you try restarting ADT? Also, a screenshot could be useful.

Comment: Well, you could try starting Eclipse from a terminal with `eclipse clean`

Comment: IDE starts up looking exactly the same with clean argument

Comment: Ok, look the tiny tab on the left? Try clicking on the first icon. Also, you could double click `Problems` tab as it seems that whole view is maximized.

Comment: see 2nd screenshot - it is an empty 'shared area'

Comment: double clicking the problems tab worked ! Could you explain that to me ?

Comment: and add it to your answer so i can tick you

Comment: Well, you can double click any tab to 'maximize' a whole Pane to full screen, but hiding the rest of them. I guess you accidentally maximized the bottom pane.

Answer (score 1):

Check the left side of the IDE and look for a folder icon. You may have acidentally minimized the Project Explorer.